# How can I process woocommerce order payment using wp-json (Rest API)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, woocommerce-rest-api

I have some unpaid order, I want to **process payment** using any of the activate getaway(Stripe,Paypal or any custom gateway) using **wp json ( using my own rest api)**. where I can pass **order_id** and **gateway id**  as param.

```
Example: I want to process payment using this kinds of url.
https://example.com/wp-json/myapp/order-payment/<order_id>/<gateway_id>
```

Please advice me how can I do that?